# Is there a way to negate the iOS force-touch expansion of IMGs?

Tags: html, ios, css, force-touch

iOS has a feature which is usually helpful where if you touch an IMG, you can expand said image by force-touching it (pushing harder). Unfortunately for my purposes, this is causing an issue on my site since I have links represented by images.

Basically if you click the picture on desktop and on mobile, it works as it should by going to the underlying link. However, there's an issue where if you push into it too much then it'll begin to blow up the image. I feel like this will confuse users and I don't want to be vulnerable to complications in things as simple as tapping a link.

I don't really know where to start. I feel like this could be a user-preferences thing that I can't actually alter but I'm hoping anyone could provide insight.

Hoping there's a HTML, CSS, or JS solution since those are the areas I'm comfortable doing myself.

```
<a href="examplelink.com">
    <img src = "" id="exPic"/>
</a>
```

Ideally iOS users won't be expanding an `img` and will instead just go to its underlying link.

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/kLv9eBW.jpg" id="exPic"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Overlay the image with a transparent element (or pseudo element)

Comment: Would that be a `div` with matching size?

Comment: Something like this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/ue6qh42n/ You can make the background colour transparent.